Move an object along a curve via an axis in geometry nodes
I have a curve that goes in all axis, and then I have an icosphere that follows the curve via a sample curve node set to length.
What I want to be able to do is keep the ico sphere following the curve, but control how far along it is on the curve via the Y axis.
So instead of what the picture shows, where the length is set to 3m and the icosphere is at 2, I would like the Icosphere to be at 3m on the y axis instead.


I made this where you divide the curve a lot (resample curve), then with a "value" (or an input, as you prefer), you can vary the Y (bottom left of the picture).
I opted for transforming the curve into a mesh because doing this with curves would be quite weird. (Later I found out this answer, which shows how to do it with pure curves - I believe "sorting" takes more time than separating, so I kept the mesh style: Curve factor at position )

